# IronPython - What kind of database is useable

Tags: database, ironpython

i'm using IronPython 2.6 for .Net4 to build an GUI logging application.

This application received data via serialport and stores these data in an sqlite3 database while showing the last 100 received items in an listview. The listview gathers it's data via an SQL SELECT from the database every 100ms. It only querys data that is not already visible in the listview.

At first, the useage of the sqlite3 module was good and solid but i'm now stuck with several issues that i can't solve. 
The sqlite3 module throws after a while exceptions like:

- database disk image is malformed
- database or disk is full.

These errors occur sporadic and never under high system load.

I stuck with this kind if issues for some weeks now and i'm looking for an alternative way to store binary and ascii data in a database-like object.

Please, does somebody know a good database solution i could use with IronPython 2.6 for .Net4?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> good

That is highly subjective without far more detailed requirements.

You should be able to use any database with .NET support, whether out of the box (notably SQL Server Express and Compact) or installed separately (SQL Server-other editions, DB2, MySQL, Oracle, ...).

Ten select commands per second should be easily in each of any of the databases above, unless there is some performance issue (e.g. huge amount of data and not able to use an index).

Comment: You are right, i forgot some requirements.

The database should be stored in a single database file, like it is with sqlite3.
The database engine should be built-in or be available as an DLL, so my application can be used on every computer with only .Net preinstalled.
The database should be able to handle one insert each 15ms (what is fastest insert it will get) while be able to handle data querys at every time.

The stored data will have an unique index, timestamp and some hundret bytes of binary data in worst case.

Comment: @flosse: Please update the question (use the edit button) to include this information in the question. Also consider "Writing the Perfect Question": http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need compatibility with CPython, then [SQL Server Compact](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2010/07/07/introducing-sql-server-compact-4-0-the-next-gen-embedded-database-from-microsoft.aspx) is probably your best bet given your requirements.